# JSON Error: Files or directories outside directory

Tags: microsoft-edge, manifest.json, microsoft-edge-extension

I tried to submit an Edge extension. It is a simple extension that had three files: the manifest.json, background.js, and an icon.

When I sideload it in Edge, it works. When I tried to publish it, I got an error that says, **Files or directories outside directory**.

I have looked everywhere for documentation on what the folder directory should look like. Can someone point me to an example directory? Should there be more folders?

Comment: Do you mean you had tried to publish the extension to the Microsoft store? If yes, did you try to create a `.zip` file of your extension to package your extension? If not, I suggest you do it and make a test with it. See reference: [Publish your extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/publish-extension).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I did zip it (compressed on a Mac) and uploaded to the MS Extension Store. It does work when I load it directly into Edge through the Extension tab using the developer option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a zip file in another way. I found an online site, but if this was something important, I would find another computer.

Anyway, it seems that Big Sur adds something extra that MS doesn't like. Strange Google accepts it.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.